# In Excel, how can I create the "intersection" of two strings (without dropping into VB)?

Tags: excel

In Mac Excel 2011, I have two strings, each consisting of a space-separated concatenation of smaller, spaceless strings. For example:

"red green blue pink"
"horse apple red monkey pink"

From those, I'd like to extract the intersection string:

"red pink"

I can do it in VB, but I'd prefer to stay in Excel proper. Now I know I could hack something together (in Excel) by making an assumption about the number of smaller component strings within each larger string. I could then chop one of the larger strings into those components and then for each do a FIND() on the second large string, concatenating the result as I went.

Problem is, although here I'm giving only two strings, in practice I have two *sets* of strings, each containing 20 large strings. So the "chop and walk" approach feels like O(N^2) in terms of space in Excel, and I'm looking for a simpler way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for a series of live functions or would a workflow be acceptable? If a workflow, you could use text to columns on each string and then use hlookups to find matches.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it in a single cell function without using multiple cells or VBA. Define a UDF like the one below and use the new function in the one cell with the syntax

```
=StringIntersect("a b c","d e b f")
```

which would return "b"

This function does have the nested loop but on string arrays I imagine it will be quick enough

```
Function StringIntersect(s1 As String, s2 As String) As String
Dim arys1()  As String
Dim arys2() As String
Dim arysub() As String
Dim i as integer
Dim j as integer

arys1 = Split(s1, " ")
arys2 = Split(s2, " ")
For i = LBound(arys1) To UBound(arys1)
    For j = LBound(arys2) To UBound(arys2)
        If arys1(i) = arys2(j) Then StringIntersect = StringIntersect & arys1(i) & " "
    Next
Next
StringIntersect = Trim(StringIntersect) 'remove trailing space
End Function
```

If you don't want to do to the two loops you should be able to do something with inStr which is very quick. I haven't done any speed testing but I suspect the function below is quicker, however you will get unexpected results is the string is duplicated in the first input or the string in the first input is a substring in the second. This could be avoided with more checking but you would probably loose the speed benefit.

```
Function StringIntersect(s1 As String, s2 As String) As String
Dim arys1()  As String

arys1 = Split(s1, " ")
For i = LBound(arys1) To UBound(arys1)
    If InStr(1, s2, arys1(i), vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then StringIntersect = StringIntersect & arys1(i) & " "
Next
StringIntersect = Trim(StringIntersect) 'remove trailing space

End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

General case for all string
Eg: StringIntersect("abcdefgh", "adefh") = "def"

```
Function StringIntersect(s1 As String, s2 As String) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

k = 1
For i = 1 To Len(s1)
    For j = 1 To Len(s2)
        Do While Mid(s1, i, k) = Mid(s2, j, k) And i + k - 1 <= Len(s1) And j + k - 1 <= Len(s2)
            StringIntersect = Mid(s1, i, k)
            k = k + 1
        Loop
    Next j
Next i

End Function
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).