# Extract text from 2 strings on excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help to do this.

I have on:
A1 cell "Portugal + Spain + UK + Belgium"
B1 cell " France + Germany + Spain + italy"

And i want on D1 the common word on a1 and b2. in this example "spain"

is this possible?

tks

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546189/in-excel-how-can-i-create-the-intersection-of-two-strings-without-dropping-i

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62726978/9758194) a more recent post which in itself again is a bit outdated. Can you let us know what version of Excel you are using?

Comment: Custards1 i  tested stringintersect but does,t work. @JvdV office 2021 professional

Comment: Not being able to use `TEXTSPLIT`, makes it hard or a large formula, because you cannot define a `LAMBDA` function inside `LET`, so everything needs to be repeated for cell `A1` and `B1`. If you want to go that road, you can check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316094/split-a-string-cell-in-excel-without-vba-e-g-for-array-formula/74092401#74092401) to a similar question. Once you have the information split, then you can use `XLOOKUP` or `INDEX/XMATCH` for example to find the match. Better to go with `FILTERXML` not available for Mac as suggested @JvdV

Answer (score 1):

I would use "Text to Columns" like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72210898/5091720). Next I would use the formula =FILTER(list1,COUNTIF(list2,list1))

So consider that list1 is in cells A1:D1 and list2 is in cells A2:D2
the next cell (what ever cell) would have the formula:

```
=FILTER(A1:D1,COUNTIF(A2:D2,A1:D1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at documentation and think the following would be supported within Excel 2021:

```
=LET(x,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),TEXTJOIN(" + ",,FILTER(x,ISNUMBER(FIND("+ "&x&" +","+ "&B1&" +")),"")))
```

Or, if you would be interested in a xpath based solution:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" + ",,FILTERXML("<x><t>"&TEXTJOIN("</s></t><t>",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")&"<s>+ "&B1)&" +</s></t></x>","//t[.//*[contains(.,concat('+ ',../text(),' +'))]]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried & I got the below ans..

[image: Result1]

in Cell **D3**

=FILTER(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" + ",,A3:B3)," + "),TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" + ",,A3:B3)," + ")=C3)

with the Filter function the result will be array.

and the basic result which supports all versions of excel is

[image: Result2]

in Cell **D3**

=IFERROR(MID($A3&" + "&$B3,SEARCH("#",SUBSTITUTE($A3&" + "&$B3,$C$3,"#",COLUMNS($D3:D3))),LEN($C$3)),"-")

have to drag the formula right side until get the result **"-"**.